# How to set a `.js` fire as node in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm, webstorm

I would like to write some simple node script in PhpStorm, however it does not recognize `process`, `require` and some other node.js variables and packages.

How can I mark a js file as node file?

Comment: cause NodeJs is not a... language?

Comment: @felipsmartins Really? :)

Comment: yep, believe me! Shhh It's A Secret ;)

Comment: Have a look at these links: 1) https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/11/node-js-coding-assistance-in-webstorm-11/ 2) https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/08/how-to-configure-code-completion-in-full-stack-javascript-projects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that **NodeJS** plugin is installed and enabled in **Settings | plugins**, and that **Node.js Core** library is enabled in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM**

See [Node.js coding assistance in WebStorm](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/11/node-js-coding-assistance-in-webstorm-11/) for more info